# Can I use VNC to control RDP sessions on Windows?

Tags: remote-desktop, vnc, vncserver, tightvnc, ultravnc

I would like to control RDP remote sessions on a Windows Server 2016 machine with VNC server.
I tried tightVNC and UltraVNC, I use `host:display` syntax to connect but I can only see the "Console" session and I cannot switch to display 1 or 2.
Is it impossibile or I'm missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be possible, but the vnc-server process must start as user-process and not as service. Then use `hostname:#` to connect, where # is the display/session nr.

Answer (score 2):

No.

Neither TightVNC nor UltraVNC can use RDP, as per [this comparison chart from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_remote_desktop_software). Sort on the second column ('Protocols') of the first chart to see the apps which do use RDP.

Comment: I try to better explain, I don't want to open a RDP session with a VNC client, I want to view/control an existing RDP session with a VNCclient.

Comment: I found that VNC works also for RDP sessions, but, I had to run vnc server from the connected user and not as service. This way i could connect to `hostname:1` and control the RDP session.

Comment: Awesome! I hope you will create an answer w/ that here and then accept it!

Answer (score 1):

Reinstall TightVNC without the start TightVNC as system service option, and put tvnserver.exe shortcut inside C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp

Comment: Please click that edit button and improve your answer, expand it, make it include more details.

Comment: This works great! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

TightVNC Server from the version 2.8.53 support connection to an active RDP session. [source](https://www.tightvnc.com/whatsnew.php)

Right know it's working only if the server autoaccept connection (no accept/reject windows).

Answer (score 0):

"Right know it's working only if the server autoaccept connection (no accept/reject windows)."
Confirming this. Regards